# Почему NAS TS-809U при копировании папки некоторым PDF файлам после точки поменял расширение с pdf на цифры (пример Аналитические данные.26376040)?

Tags: linux, хранение-данных, хранилище, nas

При создании копи папки на QNAP часть файлов в PDF формате превратилась в файлы с расширением из рандомного набора цифр  (пример Аналитические данные.26376040)??
Если сменить просто на pdf вручную, то он всё равно не открывается

Comment: копирование, небось, не закончилось, и остались временные файлы.

Comment: остановки никакой не было. часть файлов только переименовалась, а другая часть осталась в нормальном виде

Comment: смотрите логи (где находятся - см. документацию). пальцем в небо предположение: места не хватило.